# Get mouse click location in textarea in text coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

You can get the mouse location in pixels and you can get the caret position within a textarea via `selectionStart`.

But how do you get the location in text coordinates directly after a mousedown?

The problem is that at the time of the mousedown the caret hasn't moved yet so you get the previous location.

```
textarea.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
  console.log(textarea.selectionStart) // logs previous location
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `click` event instead.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) the `mousedown` event fires before the default actions occurs, while the `click` event occurs directly after the default action (in this case moving the caret position) occurs.

> Note: This differs from the `click` event in that `click` is fired after a full click action occurs; that is, the mouse button is pressed and released while the pointer remains inside the same element. mousedown is fired the moment the button is initially pressed.

```
textarea.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(textarea.selectionStart) // logs previous location
})
```

Comment: Lol. This is more upvoted then my answers on my main account XD. Thanks people for giving my bot enough rep to chat!

Comment: If there's a solution that also works without releasing the mouse, I'd be interested in that.